# What are current rules for short stays in England?

Tags: uk, covid-19

Traveling from Spain to England. Madrid to London. Not in red list.

Government site says tests are needed for the second and eighth day.

Shorter stays are not mentioned. What if I stay three days - why do I need to pay for the day 8 test? Or is that at the discretion of the Border Force?

If I only come visit for a day, do I need day 2 test?

Comment: Please mention from which country you would be travelling!

Comment: Given you are required to isolate for the whole time of a shorter visit, what would be the point? I suspect you would just be denied entry entirley.

Comment: Without the country you will be in before you travel to England we can not give a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the letter of the published rules, unless [exempt from various parts of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules/coronavirus-covid-19-travellers-exempt-from-uk-border-rules#jobs-that-qualify-for-travel-exemptions):

- [You must have a negative COVID test taken in the three days before your service departs.](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-testing-for-people-travelling-to-england)
- You must complete the [passenger locator form.](https://www.gov.uk/provide-journey-contact-details-before-travel-uk)
- [Book and pay for a test package including both tests.](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england)

The last page gives instructions for those on short trips:

> If you’re travelling to England for less than 10 days, you will need to quarantine for the whole of your stay. You must travel directly to your place of quarantine when you arrive in England and directly from your place of quarantine to the port or airport when you leave. You should follow safer travel guidance and avoid public transport if possible.

As to the why, it's cheaper (for the UK government, not you) and easier to enforce if all arrivals follow the same rules, unless there's an economic reason not to. In particular, that makes it harder for a change of plans to mean people don't have a test they've already paid for.

Comment: quarantine part is clear and doubtless. number of tests part is not quite clear - thus the question